# jQuery custom attr is not working in option tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have select type with having custom attr in option tag. When i am able to get the val, but not able to get the value in custom attribute.

Here is Jsfiddle

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c1r4ujeb/)

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('change','.selectedItem',function() {
    
        var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
        alert(selectedValue);
        alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
        var product_id = jQuery(this).attr('rel-product-id');
        alert(product_id);
        var product_name= jQuery(this).attr("rel-product-name");
        alert(product_name);
        
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you also share your HTML code to us?

Comment: Please see jsfiddle. already have code there

Comment: `jQuery(this).attr('rel-product-id')` is mean get attr of `select`, you need to get `option` is selected, try  `jQuery(this).find(":selected").attr("id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you're trying to get the values of the attributes from the `select` itself. What you want to do is to get them from the selected `option` of the `select` using `option:selected`. Like this:

```
alert(jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('id'));
alert(jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('rel-product-id'));
alert(jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('rel-product-name'));
```